# Unable to cast the type X to type Y. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I completely understand this error, but is there a way to implement some code so that linq to entities understands that my custom type should be treated as a `decimal` primitive type?

I've created a custom `Money` type that accepts a nullable `decimal` to one of its constructor overloads. It has implicit operator overloading and all other kinds of cool jazz on it. I want to use this custom type in my linq to entities projections but alas the error in the title.

Is there an attribute that I can declare on my `Money` type that says, "Hey, for the purposes of linq projections I'm of primitive type `decimal`"?

Is there some way a custom expression tree/visitor can help here to declare that all types of `Money` are to be treated as `decimal` primitives for linq projections?

```
[HeyImADecimalForLinqProjections] // custom attribute
public class Money : IComparable<Money>
{
    public Money()
    {
        Value = decimal.Zero;
    }
    public Money(decimal? value)
    {
        if (value.HasValue)
            Value = value.Value;
        else
            Value = decimal.Zero;
    }
    public static implicit operator Money(decimal value)
    {
        return new Money(value);
    }
    public static implicit operator Money(decimal? value)
    {
        return new Money(value.Value);
    }
    ...
}
```

Example projection:

```
var items = orderQuery.Where(a => a.OrderId = 345)
    .Select(a => new OrderModel()
        {
            OrderId = a.OrderId,
            SubtotalIncludingTax = a.SubtotalIncludingTax, // no dice, SubtotalIncludingTax is of type Money - Unable to cast the type 'System.Decimal' to type 'Money'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.
            SubtotalIncludingTaxRaw = a.SubtotalIncludingTax, // this is fine because SubtotalIncludingTaxRaw is of type decimal
        })
    .ToList();
```

---

My current solution works but I hate it. I project to an anonymous type first, then project the anonymous type to my actual model. This example is extremely watered down and this double projection solution results in a lot of repetition that I'd rather avoid.

```
// first get everything as anonymous projection objects in linq to entities
var anonymousItems = orderQuery.Where(a => a.OrderId = 345)
    .Select(a =>
        {
            OrderId = a.OrderId,
            SubtotalIncludingTax = a.SubtotalIncludingTax // decimal to decimal
    .ToList();

// now cast to our actual model since we are back in .Net world
var items = anonymousItems
    .Select(a => new OrderModel()
        {
            OrderId = a.OrderId,
            SubtotalIncludingTax = a.SubtotalIncludingTax // decimal to Money
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Just a shot in the dark here, but can you set up another implicit operator that works the other way, i.e. converts `Money` to `decimal`?  I don't know if that would be enough to satisfy linq, but it would be worth a shot: https://dotnetfiddle.net/QLaccg

Comment: It actually has the implicit conversion for both `Money` to `decimal` and `Money` to `Nullable<decimal>` but no dice. I also implemented a slew of interfaces hoping one would do it but again, no dice. `IComparable, IComparable<string>, IComparable<decimal>, IComparable<decimal?>, IComparable<Money>, IEquatable<string>, IEquatable<decimal>, IEquatable<decimal?>, IEquatable<Money>, IFormattable, IValueProvider, IValidatableObject, IConvertible, ICloneable`

Answer (score 2):

At this time Entity  Framework does not support casting like this.  You could have a workaround with a mapped property and an unmapped property such as:

```
public decimal RawTotalIncludingTax {get;set;}
public Money TotalIncludingTax 
{ 
   get { return RawTotalIncludingtax; }
   set { RawTotalIncludingTax = value; }
}
```

This would likely save the additional anonymous type to concrete type selects, but still leaves you with a similar problem.  The more likely solution that would help would be an extension method to do things like:

```
using System;

public static class MoneyExtensions
{
    public static string Format(this decimal val){
        if(val < 0)
            return "(" + Math.Abs(val).ToString("N2") + ")";
        else
            return val.ToString("N2");
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(2.2m.Format());
        Console.WriteLine((-12.42m).Format());
    }
}
```

This way you would not need the custom type, but could still get the use out of the MoneyExtensions and syntax you are after!